# How to know whether the server supports caching of data or not from the API response?

Tags: java, android, server, android-volley, cache-control

I would like to know whether the server from which I am getting the response supports cache or not.

Where to find, Cache-control: no-cache or Cache-control: cache from server response?

Note: I am using Volley library to get and parse the JSON response from the server.

Comment: Ask the backend team. You can't tell by the header. Are you afraid to communicate with other teams?

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your comment. I am not afraid to communicate with other teams. I have asked and confirmed that cache is supported by default by the framework what we use. I just would like to know whether we can find it through the server response or not. I think you have given me the right answer('You can't tell by the header'). Once again thanks man :)

Comment: @Kayaman did you downvote this question? I researched enough and couldn't find the answer for my question anywhere in the internet. I was only need to confirm it with the backend team. I was just wondering how can we know the cache ability of the server from the response.